Needed Clarification on Frontend-to-Backend Communication
We have received the penetration test report for our application, but unfortunately, we do not have access to the person who performed the test. One of the reported issues is as follows:

"The application in its current form seems to use an architecture where the frontend is meant to only serve static files (JavaScript, etc.) and all data is served directly from the backend to the user's browser. During the intake of the penetration test, the expected design was that only the frontend URL would communicate with the user's browser, and the backend server would only communicate with the frontend server."

I’m unsure of how the frontend (React app) server would directly communicate with the backend server. Based on my understanding, the browser receives static files to render from the frontend server. Any API requests are then made from the browser to the backend. I am planning to put a Gateway or reverse proxy in front of the backend but am unsure if this will satisfy the expected architecture.
Can someone clarify what is meant by direct communication from the frontend to the backend in this context?

That wording is awkward for sure. It does sound like they are trying to indicate that the frontend is talking directly to the server with no intermediary (reverse proxy, BFF (Backend For Frontend) etc.) Adding this layer will ensure that the UI can't make escalated privilege requests to the server, and data served back to the frontend is filtered as needed. PS saying you can't contact the pen test report author, sounds like you were sent a graceful heads up of security issues, is this what happened?

Thank you! A heads up would have been nice, but no the person is on a long vacation. And we are in not in the US, so the vacation is respected as no access time
